# Unable to get "true condition" on a found element in a select list and select it

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir

I'm using Watir 6 with Rspec and i'm having trouble accessing a select list and selecting one of the options.

The URL is: https://www.fundingcircle.com/businesses/apply?video=true

The code in question which is failing is:

```
browser.select_list(name: 'loan_product').select('Working capital')
```

HTML:

```html
<select name="loan_product" required="" ng-model="prequal.borrower.loan_product" ng-options="product as product.label for product in prequal.loanProducts" styled-select="" placeholder="Please select..." fc-input="" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required fc-touched">
<option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option><option value="0" label="Working capital">Working capital</option><option value="1" label="Expansion/growth">Expansion/growth</option><option value="2" label="Refinancing a loan">Refinancing a loan</option><option value="3" label="Asset finance">Asset finance</option><option value="4" label="Tax payment">Tax payment</option><option value="5" label="Commercial mortgage">Commercial mortgage</option><option value="6" label="Other">Other</option></select>
```

The error I keep on receiving regardless of how many times I have tried changing the code is:

```
This code has slept for the duration of the default timeout waiting for an Element to be present. If the test is still passing, consider using Element#exists? instead of rescuing UnknownObjectException
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on {:name=>"loan_product", :tag_name=>"select"}
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/watir-6.0.2/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:528:in `rescue in wait_for_present'
```

The elements exist and all select list options show as true, but unfortunately they don't seem to be visible or present according to the test. Last option I feel is to manipulate the javascript, but I don't want to go down this route if I can help it. I would really appreciate it if someone could put me on the right path and advise how I can get past this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What browser/versions are you using? The select list was selected for me when using Firefox v 50.1 and Chrome v55.

Comment: I noticed that when the page loads, there is a "loading" image instead of the form controls. If you watch the script run (or take a screenshot), do you see the form controls load before the 30 second timeout?

Comment: Hi Justin, I am using Chrome v55. Yes, there is a loading image that comes up after a while but I get the same issue even when the image has come and gone. Did you manage to select an option successfully when you ran the test? because it's not working for me.

Comment: @Azher Yes, it's coming but only when I use Chrome, not when I use Firefox, did you try with firefox?

Comment: @Azher, yes, the option was successfully selected for me. Are you using the latest Chromedriver - v2.26?

Comment: @JustinKo I am using chromedriver v2.26, but still that error is coming, but it's not happening in firefox.

Comment: @Justin HHmmm I am using Chrome 55.0.2883.95 and Chromedriver -v2.26. I'm still getting same issue. Did you do something different or just use the same code that I posted above?

Comment: @Azher, I just copy and pasted your code (plus added a line to open Chrome and directly navigate to the URL). I wonder if it is an OS specific bug. I'm on Windows, which means I am using the win32 version of chromedriver with the latest stable Chrome release which is still just 55.0.2883.87.

Comment: @JustinKo Thank you for your help and identifying the issue. Titusfortner came up with a solution that works. It's a weird one and I will be raising this as a chromedriver bug as i'm sure i'll probably come across this again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird one. On my mac the select list shows as visible in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Watir checks for select list to be visible before trying to click on the option. The option element is implemented in Selenium so that it will always return as visible.

So this will work for you:

```
browser.option(label: 'Working capital').click
```

I'm not sure why they are different, or what the issue is on Windows vs Chrome. Presumably chromedriver is using the same isDisplayed javascript code as geckodriver. You could probably raise this as a chromedriver bug.

Comment: Thanks titusfortner, this actually works. It was a weird issue and I will be raising a chromedriver bug. Once again thank you for finding a solution to what was a blocker.